# error in running the job using gitlab runner

Tags: devops, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I registered a runner is my gitlab docker container as you can see :

[image]

And this is my .gitlab-ci.yml file

```
image: mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:latest
.shared_windows_runners:
  tags:
    - shared-windows
    - windows
    - windows-1809
    


stages:
    - build
    - test
    

build:
    stage: build
    script:
        - "dotnet build"
    artifacts:
      paths:
        - bin/

test:
    stage: test
    script: 
        - "dotnet test"
```

But my job is on pending state

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have tagged your job:

```
  tags:
    - shared-windows
    - windows
    - windows-1809
```

But judging from your screenshot it seems that you did not tag your runner with these tags. Either remove the tags from the job definition or tag the runner.

Comment: Yes you are right but I added these tags to runner but it didn't work again , I also checked this option :Indicates whether this runner can pick jobs without tags in runner setting

Comment: Please add more information regarding your runner configuration.